# Angular 8: Pass Disabled attribute while using addControl Method is not working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am dynamically creating the forms and dynamically adding input controls into the forms. Below is my code:

```
(<FormGroup>this.formsArr[formName]) = new FormGroup({}); 
this.formsArr[formName].addControl(formControlName, new FormControl('abc', []));
```

In Html:

```
<input
    type="text"
    placeholder="{{ fieldObj.placeholder }}"
    [disabled]="fieldObj.disabledValue"
    [readonly]="fieldObj.readOnlyValue">
```

if readOnlyValue is true then above input box is setting to readonly but in case of disabled it is not working and throwing warning in browser to set it while creating new FormControl({value: 'abc', disabled: true})

and here i want to pass default disabled property. Below is my code for that:

```
this.formsArr[formName].addControl(formControlName, new FormControl({value: 'abc', disabled: true}[]));
```

But i am getting default input value as [Object Object] in input box and input box is also not getting disabled.

Comment: Could you please create a working example in https://stackblitz.com/??

Answer (score 3):

Here and example that works for me if I undestand properly what you mean

```
this.requestForm.addControl('ticketCauses', new FormControl({ value: [], 
     disabled: true }, Validators.required));
```

Where
ticketCauses is the formControl name
value: [] is the initial value
disabled: true set that field disabled by default
Validators.required is a validator to require that field not to be empty